# Avoiding build twice when using a shared project together with build generated code

Tags: visual-studio, project

I have a visual studio solution with multiple projects. One generates code files as part of pre-build (grpc classes via Grpc.Tools). There is also a shared project that extends the partial classes built as part of that pre-build.

However, *sometimes* for one reason or another - like compiling the client half of this (client uses the shared project to extend its own classes), compilation will error because the shared project can't find the generated classes yet. Presumably they don't exist. It's fixed easily by compiling the project twice.

Is there something I can do in this scenario? Is it possible to somehow move validating/compiling the shared project "further down" the compilation pipeline? Or even just set that particular project to try and compile twice if there's an error? Or is this the kind of thing that realistically I should just live with given what I'm doing - I haven't found any other references to this problem. It's not *that* big of an issue and it wouldn't happen very often, but I'd like to handle it reasonably if I can.

**Edit**

If I wasn't clear, this is a shared project, as in a .shproj, a project that is not compiled separately. The project that references it includes it and builds it all together as one.

Comment: It sounds like you got a race condition during compilation. Apparently the compiler of the reference project returns, before the files have been fully written. That however should be impossible. Maybe there is a 3rd programm, that acces the files?

Comment: I don't know exactly when Grpc.Tools is creating those classes, or when the shared project is validated alongside the main project. But you're right, it's obviously making the classes during the first failed build.. or doing something that makes it work?

Comment: Does the second project actually depend on the first project? Or is it expecting to find the generated classes using the file system without any help from Visual Studio?

Comment: @Flater Which second project are you referring to? The shared project?

Comment: @cost: Whichever project you're expecting to go second, not first.

Answer (score 1):

If project B depends on project A, then project A **must** be built before project B. Visual Studio is smart enough to figure out the build order this way. Incidentally, this is also one of the reasons (among many) why circular dependencies simply cannot work.

I suspect that your projects are currently not linked via a dependency, as this issue wouldn't occur if there were such a link. Perhaps your second project is accessing the first project's files via the file system? That's just a guess though.

You can use this "A before B which depends on A" behavior of the build process to your advantage. Have project B (i.e. the project you need to go second) add project A (i.e. the project you need to go first) as a dependency. This forces VS to build them in the appropriate order.

---

Some remarks:

- I am unsure if VS is able to omit dependencies that you add but not actually depend on (i.e. you never reference its content). I can't find any confirmation on this point (but absence of proof is not proof of absence!) But even if that is the case, that could be easily worked around by having a dummy class in B which actually references and uses something from project A.
- Keep in mind that during a regular build, VS does not rebuild projects that have not changed since the last build. If this is an issue for you (unsure if it is, you didn't add enough context), make sure to always rebuild or clean to make sure that a new build will be triggered.

Comment: See my edit, I think you are thinking about a project reference, not a shared project. They would be built as one project as far as I know. Apologies if I'm incorrect about this.

Answer (score 0):

> However, sometimes for one reason or another - like compiling the client half of this (client uses the shared project to extend its own classes), compilation will error because the shared project can't find the generated classes yet. Presumably they don't exist. It's fixed easily by compiling the project twice.

That it is only sometimes and can be fixed by "trying again" points at one thing - you got [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). But a race condition during compilation, is not a thing I heard off or encountered before.

I got a few possible cultripts. But in the end, race conditions are notoriously hard to debug:
 - Maybe the compiler that deals with the shared project returns before it is finished - wich should be impossible - or 
 - Maybe something causes the main projects to compile before the shared projects files are ready.
 - Maybe a 3rd party tool - like a Virus scanner or auto backup maker inteferes? 
 - Maybe the shared projects compiled files are hosted on a network drive, and there sometimes is just the slightest delay between "compiled" and "visible to all other computers in the network"?

Usually the proper ways for dependant compilation should deal with such issues. That indicates that what you got there, is propably not the most stable setup.

Comment: Not sure if I was clear on this (I made an edit), this is a shared project, not a project reference, which means it is added to the main project and compiled all as one. A build action triggers the class creation, and the shared project references that class. The first build that fails presumably creates the files, but something about the way the shared project is checked, it doesn't see them in that first build.

Comment: @cost Something in that whole process sounds very abnormal. There are proper ways to do what you want, but it sounds like you cobelled together some homebrew solution instead. Of course your homebrew will be less reiable then anything that was tested as rigorously as a proper, official IDE or Version Control Software feature.

Comment: Grpc adds some complexity because it generates its classes as part of a build action. You're right, I'm doing something somewhat custom here, but it's to keep from duplicating code in two projects - which is what a shared project was supposed to be for. I wouldn't expect build actions and shared projects working together to be *that much* out of the norm, but I so far haven't found any better alternatives to my particular scenario.